# VTK - calculate point cloud for a renderered scene

Tags: c++, 3d, vtk

I render a triangulated mesh (polydata) using VTK renderer. I want to get a 3D point cloud of the rendered scene (with respect to the camera).

I found a similar snippet where do the similar thing in the [PCL library](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/visualization/src/pcl_visualizer.cpp#L3852) which uses VTK as its visualisation tool.

I implement the PCL function in my code and I managed to get same results (3D point cloud).
However, I found an issue that I don't know where to start to solve:

- For a point that should have valid depth value in the z-buffer, 1 (I believe it is a default set value means NOT a valid point) is returned.

I tried to play with the clippingplane (also known as nearz/farz), but nothing improved.

**UPDATE:**
Issue solved, it was because I forget VTK defined image coordinate differently than the traditional one. In VTK, origin is bottom-left instead of top-left.

Answer (score 0):

Renderer will transform display <--> world coordinates. Look at methods of class `vtkViewport`: `SetDisplayPoint()`, `DisplayToWorld()`, `GetWorldPoint()`.
This API uses homogeneous coordinates. Look at the source of any vtk widget -- during interaction the display coordinates are transformed to world coordinates.

But if you are trying to get coordinates of a point lying on a surface, you really want a `vtkPointPicker` or `vtkCellPicker`. Look at examples and tests of these classes.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on that same problem. I am using vtk's python bindings but I think you will be interested in looking at the method `RequestData()` in [this question that I recently posted.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440195/vtkpythonalgorithm-controlling-pipeline-execution) My question is about pipeline execution and not about projecting points.

mirni's answer definitely works, but if you are doing that for every pixel you will do an extra two matrix creations, a matrix multiply, and a matrix multiply for each pixel.

Doing it the way I did in my method saved about 16 seconds on a 300x300 window.

Comment: Thanks for the information, in my case, the speed bottleneck seems not at the transformation but how I get the depth by calling RenderWindow::GetZbufferData(). How do you get the depth from the renderwindow?

Comment: @linzhang.robot I can imagine that is a bottleneck. I use vtkWindowToImageFilter(). You can see that in the post I referred you to. Also, here is an [example in C++](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/ZBuffer). Be sure to read [this warning](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkWindowToImageFilter.html#details)

Comment: Yes, I used `vtkWindowToImageFilter` as well and though maybe GetZbufferData directly could be faster. I used `vtkWindowToImageFilter` to get color image of my render window, the function `vtkWindowToImageFilter::Update` actually takes a lot of time as well. I wonder if this is caused by some inefficient vtk memory copy operation b/w GPU and CPU.

Comment: @linzhang.robot Looking at the RequestData() method in vtkWindowToImageFilter() it does look like you can save some overhead by calling `GetZbufferData` directly [see here](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Rendering/Core/vtkWindowToImageFilter.cxx#L533). They only thing that would be closer to the metal would be somehow calling `glGetBufferSubData()` which is an OpenGL call. (Assuming your backend is OpenGL) Maybe there is a clue in this class: [vtkOpenGLBufferObject](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkOpenGLBufferObject.h)