# vtkPythonAlgorithm Controlling pipeline execution

Tags: python, vtk

I am trying to write a vtk filter in python `ProjectDepthImage` Doing the projection isn't the problem. It's controlling the execution of the vtk pipeline.

Basically, I have a callback on 'UserEvent' (which is triggered when a user hits the key 'u' while the render window is active.) This calls the function: `render_point_cloud()` I have found that I need to call both dif.Modified() and pdi.Update() in this callback or I will get unexpected results. However, by doing this this RequestData() gets executed twice, as indicated by the print statement.

I really want to use the VTK pipeline correctly, and I want RequestData() to be executed only once when the user hits 'u'

I have to call Modified() on dif because of the way vtkWindowToImageFilter works: http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkWindowToImageFilter.html#details

Best post on `vtkPythonAlgorthim` that I have found: https://blog.kitware.com/vtkpythonalgorithm-is-great/

```
import vtk

from vtk.util import numpy_support
from vtk.numpy_interface import dataset_adapter as dsa
from vtk.numpy_interface import algorithms as alg

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from timeit import default_timer as timer
import time


# import vtk
from vtk.util.vtkAlgorithm import VTKPythonAlgorithmBase


class ProjectDepthImage(VTKPythonAlgorithmBase):
    def __init__(self):
        VTKPythonAlgorithmBase.__init__(self,
                                        nInputPorts=1, inputType='vtkImageData',
                                        nOutputPorts=1, outputType='vtkPolyData')
        self.__ren = []
        self.__renWin = []

        self.__display_pts = []
        self.__viewport_pts = []
        self.__world_pts = []
        self.__sizex = []
        self.__sizey = []

    def SetRenderer(self, renderer):
        if renderer != self.__ren:
            self.__ren = renderer
            self.Modified()

    def GetRenderer(self):
        return self.__ren

    def SetRenderWindow(self, render_window):
        if render_window != self.__renWin:
            self.__renWin = render_window
            self.Modified()

    def GetRenderWindow(self):
        return self.__renWin

    def RequestData(self, request, inInfo, outInfo):
        print 'Executing'

        # all the depth values
        inp = dsa.WrapDataObject(vtk.vtkImageData.GetData(inInfo[0]))
        depth = numpy_support.vtk_to_numpy(inp.PointData['ImageScalars'])

        # update the viewport points, check to see if render window size has changed
        self.__update_viewport_points(depth)

        # transformation matrix, viewport coordinates -> world coordinates
        tmat = ren.GetActiveCamera().GetCompositeProjectionTransformMatrix(
            ren.GetTiledAspectRatio(),
            0.0, 1.0)
        tmat.Invert()
        tmat = self.__vtkmatrix_to_numpy(tmat)

        # project to world coordinates
        self.__world_pts = np.dot(tmat, self.__viewport_pts)
        self.__world_pts = self.__world_pts / self.__world_pts[3]

        # for storing the point cloud
        points = vtk.vtkPoints()
        vertices = vtk.vtkCellArray()
        polydata = vtk.vtkPolyData()
        out = vtk.vtkPolyData.GetData(outInfo)
        for i in np.arange(self.__world_pts.shape[1]):
            pt_id = points.InsertNextPoint(self.__world_pts[0:3, i])
            vertices.InsertNextCell(1)
            vertices.InsertCellPoint(pt_id)
        polydata.SetPoints(points)
        polydata.SetVerts(vertices)
        out.ShallowCopy(polydata)

        return 1

    def __update_viewport_points(self, depth):
        # if the render windows size has not changed, just return
        if (self.__sizex, self.__sizey) == self.__renWin.GetSize():
            self.__viewport_pts[2, :] = depth
            return

        # save the new size
        (self.__sizex, self.__sizey) = self.__renWin.GetSize()
        # new display points
        self.__display_pts = np.ones((2, self.__sizex*self.__sizey))
        count = 0
        for i in np.arange(self.__sizey):
            for j in np.arange(self.__sizex):
                self.__display_pts[0, count] = j
                self.__display_pts[1, count] = i
                count += 1
        # new viewport points
        viewport = self.__ren.GetViewport()
        self.__viewport_pts = np.ones((4, self.__display_pts.shape[1]))
        self.__viewport_pts[0,:] = 2.0 * (self.__display_pts[0,:] - self.__sizex*viewport[0]) / (self.__sizex*(viewport[2]-viewport[0])) - 1.0
        self.__viewport_pts[1,:] = 2.0 * (self.__display_pts[1,:] - self.__sizey*viewport[1]) / (self.__sizey*(viewport[3]-viewport[1])) - 1.0
        self.__viewport_pts[2,:] = depth
        # new world points (of the right size)
        self.__world_pts = np.ones(self.__viewport_pts.shape)

    def __vtkmatrix_to_numpy(self, matrix):
        """
        Copies the elements of a vtkMatrix4x4 into a numpy array.
        :type matrix: vtk.vtkMatrix4x4
        :param matrix: The matrix to be copied into an array.
        :rtype: numpy.ndarray
        """
        m = np.ones((4, 4))
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(4):
                m[i, j] = matrix.GetElement(i, j)
        return m


def render_point_cloud(obj, env):
    start = timer()

    dif.Modified()
    pdi.Update()

    end = timer()
    print(end-start)


# ren, renWin, iren - vtk rendering objects
ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)
iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

# create cube
cube = vtk.vtkCubeSource()
cube.SetCenter(0, 0, 0)
cubeMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
cubeMapper.SetInputConnection(cube.GetOutputPort())
cubeActor = vtk.vtkActor()
cubeActor.SetMapper(cubeMapper)
ren.AddActor(cubeActor)

# set camera intrinsic params to mimic kinect
renWin.SetSize(640, 480)
ren.GetActiveCamera().SetViewAngle(60.0)
ren.GetActiveCamera().SetClippingRange(0.1, 10.0)
iren.GetInteractorStyle().SetAutoAdjustCameraClippingRange(0)
ren.GetActiveCamera().SetPosition(0.0, 0.0, 2.0)

# has to be initialized before filter is update
# not sure why
iren.Initialize()

# dif (depth image filter)
# Filter that grabs the vtkRenderWindow and returns
# the depth image (in this case)
dif = vtk.vtkWindowToImageFilter()
dif.SetInputBufferTypeToZBuffer()
dif.SetInput(ren.GetVTKWindow())
dif.Update()

# pdi (project depth image)
# Gets output of dif and projects the coordinates into world coordinate system
pdi = ProjectDepthImage()
pdi.SetRenderer(ren)
pdi.SetRenderWindow(renWin)
pdi.SetInputConnection(dif.GetOutputPort())
pdi.Update()

# for displaying the point cloud
mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(pdi.GetOutputPort())
actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)
actor.GetProperty().SetPointSize(2)
rgb = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
colors = vtk.vtkNamedColors()
colors.GetColorRGB("red", rgb)
actor.GetProperty().SetColor(rgb)
ren.AddActor(actor)

# needed for first image in loop to be current
ren.Render()
dif.Modified()
pdi.Update()

iren.AddObserver('UserEvent', render_point_cloud)

iren.Start()
```